# ios NSError types

Tags: ios

Ever since I added this *async* request, I'm getting an xcode error of `Sending 'NSError *const __strong *' to parameter of type 'NSError *__autoreleasing *' changes retain/release properties of pointer`

```
...
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data error:&error];
        ...
    });
}];
...
```

If I use `error:nil` then my code runs fine, but I feel *uneasy* about not using errors.. What should I do?

Comment: If you're not actually doing anything with the error you may as well just pass NULL. You can usually detect if an error has occurred anyway because the method returns nil, so it's not like you'll be missing the fact that errors are happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Presumably it's because you're reusing the `error` passed in to you in the completion handler. It'll be being passed as `__strong` and then you pass it in where it is required to be `__autoreleasing`. Try changing to this code:

```
...
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSError *error2 = nil;
        NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data error:&error2];
        ...
    });
}];
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This Xcode error happens when put `NSError *error=nil;` definition **outside** the ^block.

Inside the block, then `error:&error` works fine.