# issue with autoreleasing pointers and functions

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a function that has the following signature:

```
- (void)addSource:(NSDictionary *)sourceDetails toPage:(NSString *)pageTitle error:(NSError **)error {

}
```

then I tried to call it as follows:

```
NSError *error = nil;
  [[TestManager sharedInstance] addSource:obj toPage:selectedPageTitle error:&error];
```

but then it always gives me the following error:

```
Sending 'NSError *const __strong *' to parameter of type 'NSError *__autoreleasing *' changes retain/release properties of pointer
```

This just happened after I upgraded XCode yesterday, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ios NSError types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203044/ios-nserror-types).  The general solution/answer is the same.

Comment: That should be correct, you shouldn't have that warning. The __strong variable error is copied to another one __autoreleasing.